# Trace who moved our folder in random directory

Tags: linux

Hi everyone I need your help, 
someone moved our api folder to a random directory.
I already recovered it and move it to where it placed.
But our managers want to know who did it and they are pointing at me. I didn't open our server today so I want to trace down the user who did that and show it to our managers.

Is there any command in Linux or something?

Comment: If you haven't logged you have no chance. Ask your coworkers!

Comment: Hi Ipor, thanks for replying. What kind of logs are you referring to? Is there any system logs that i can access in order to check their id or actions and their history like that?

Comment: There are no any logs default. If you set up for example [auditd](https://linux.die.net/man/8/auditd) then logs could be created.

Comment: Ohh i see, Thanks Ipor.. just for now, ill let them blame me for that and enable that log so i can trace the user next time.

Comment: If you didn't log in, you may be able to use `auth.log` to see who was logged in around the time the directory was moved. Also, checking `~/.bash_history` or equivalent may also point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if you want to see who did it, there won't be an exact log, but there may be clues.

1) Can you find out when the folder was moved? Either find out when your app stopped working, or you may be able to get info from the time stamps of the parent folder that the file was moved out of or in to (assuming other files/folders haven't been updated there, too).

2) Who was logged in at that time? the `last` command or the login logs in /var/log (maybe `/var/log/secure` or `/var/log/auth`) may give a hint. Hopefully, you don't share user accounts between people.

3) If the person used `sudo` or `su`, the command may be recorded in /var/log/secure.log (or auth.log or others, depending on which linux you're using), depending on how they ran the command. If the person who made the change ran something like `sudo mv file /new/spot/file`, then you may be able to "grep file /var/log/...'